# Understanding f_classif in sklearn

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, anova

Recently to get best features I have used SelectKBest(score_func=, k=20). f_classif computes anova f-value between feature for classification tasks. I have used it and got best results. I learnt anova f-test computes ratio of 'between class variance' to 'within class variance'. But I have following questions:

1) Does f_classif use combination of features to give f-score ?.
2) Can I have a pseudo code of how fit function of SelectKBest works ?. 
3) How does f_classif work in sklearn ?. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

f_classif is done on a feature by feature basis, i.e. individually. So no combination of features.